# video recording issue in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, getusermedia, video-recording

I have implemented video recording functionality in reactjs by using MediaDevices.getUserMedia() but audio quality is not good, System is creating lots of annoying voice from a background that is very irritable.
link:https://devionashell.azurewebsites.net/uco

```
startVideos = async () => {

stopCountdown = false;
this.setState({
    open: true
});
var constraints = {
    audio: {
        sampleRate: 44800,
        channelCount: 2,
        volume: 0.2,
        autoGainControl: false,
        echoCancellation: false,
        noiseSuppression: false,
        googleAutoGainControl: false,
        sampleSize: 16


    },
    video: {
        facingMode: "environment"
    }
}


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.mediaDevices.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mediaDevices.mozGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    // show it to user
    vid = stream;

    this.video.srcObject = stream;
    this.video.volume = 0.1;
    // var vid_volume = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    console.log('vid_volume')
    //  console.log(vid_volume)
    console.log('vid_volume')
    //this.video.volumeObject = 0.2;
    this.video.play();

    // init recording
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: videoType,
    });
    // init data storage for video chunks
    this.chunks = [];
    // listen for data from media recorder
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
        if (e.data && e.data.size > 0) {
            this.chunks.push(e.data);
        }
    };
    this.render();
} else {
    console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

}

Comment: Please add a sample of your code.

Comment: Kindly add minimum reproducable code, so it will be helpful to find the problem

Comment: Also please give a description of your microphone setup. Do you use the built-in mic of a laptop? Do you record in a room with many people talking, or machine (a/c) sounds? Please [edit] your question to give us more information so we can help you.